# Different applications, different sound output devices

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, configuration, devices, output

I would find it really useful if I could make it so that music I am playing on YouTube in Chrome comes out of speakers, and the sound from other applications comes out of my earphones, so I am wondering if there is a way to get it so that different applications use different sound devices to output? And an easy way of quickly changing which application has which output device assigned to it.

I found another question about this here: [Play sound from different applications on different output devices (speakers, headphones)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181704/play-sound-from-different-applications-on-different-output-devices-speakers-he) But that question is 2 years old and had no answers, so I decided that I should ask a new question about this.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: As commented on that question, `pavucontrol` should allow you to do this in the output tab (by application). If not, you would have to use jack .

Comment: Screenshot - http://i.stack.imgur.com/gwous.png Assuming that works this comment can be converted to an answer. Configuring jack would be different

Comment: Of course, I believe you would need more then one sound card as I doubt the average sound card can do both speakers and head phones with 2 apps at the same time . If you have problems you may need to configure jack and you may need to modify some desktop settings and/or a realtime kernel (although in theory the rt patch is no longer needed).

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I think that the thing about `pavucontrol` will work, so could you please convert that into an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is going to vary with hardware and my guess is that you need 2 separate sound cards or a sound card / mixer capable of such separation.

You can then configure pulseausio to send output to specific locations / cards with `pavucontrol` , in the playback tab

[image: pavucontrol]

One may need to install pavucontrol , either with apt-get or from the software center.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

If for some reason, pulseaudio will not do this, jack will, but configuring jack can be overwhelming. If you are new to jack, I suggest Cadence, with is a graphical tool provided as a binary

http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/Downloads

Comment: I can confirm `pavucontrol` works with speakers over bluetooth and headphones over jack with sound from two different browsers. I have only one soundcard and a bluetooth dongle via USB.

Comment: Do you by chance know how to set this up for system sounds? (I want those on the speaker, so I don't miss meeting notifications when I don't have my earphones in my ears.)

Comment: This works for me without multiple soundcards. Same as @bennos. @Paŭlo Ebermann You could just set your desired output device for the system in `gnome-settings` then change the output device for the audio app/browser in `pavucontrol`