# Different Sound Output Devices for Different Applications? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, speakers

I would like to output the sound from different applications through different speakers/headphones (pulseaudio sinks). For example, music from a youtube video or a media player through speakers, but sound from a game through headphones.

Is there a good way to do this? I only found pretty outdated answers to this, which I couldn't get to work for one reason or another.

Comment: Add the output of `inxi -A; aplay -l`. Sounds identical to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181704/play-sound-from-different-applications-on-different-output-devices-speakers-he). [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609292/different-applications-different-sound-output-devices) if you have two cards.